# How to access preferences in a static method

Tags: android

So I have a broadcast receiver that needs to notify a service that it has received a text message. The only way to do this (as far as I know) is a static method. But the method that is notified need access to the application's preferences.

Every method I have tried says that it cannot be accessed from a static method. So how do I access preferences from a static method?

Comment: Could you share a sample of the code from the Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only way to do this (as far as I know) is a static method.

Hardly. In fact, that approach is not recommended.

If the service is supposed to be in memory when the broadcast is received, have the service register the `BroadcastReceiver` via `registerReceiver()` and handle it directly. If the service is not supposed to be in memory when the broadcast is received, use `startService()` to start the service and send over an `Intent` (picked up in `onStart()` of the service).

> So how do I access preferences from a static method?

See Pentium10's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, so when I register the receiver, how will I know when something has been received?

Comment: Actually, I have kind of reworked what I am doing, I now have the receiver set to start the service and send over the intent, but I could have multiple text messages come in, so how can I send over another one once the service is already started? (I am still curious as to the answer of the first question)

Comment: @Andrew Guenther: "when I register the receiver, how will I know when something has been received?" -- because the receiver is called with `onReceive()`. Make it be an inner class of the service, and it can call methods on the service. "how can I send over another one once the service is already started?" -- call `startService()` again. Ideally, your service is an `IntentService`, which processes Intents on a background thread, queues up `Intents` if needed, and automatically shuts down when there is no more work to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `context` param of your `BroadcastReceiver` to get access to stuff that belongs to `Context`, such as `getSharedPreferences`

To see some code samples of working with `SharedPreferences` see this other question [Making data persistent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310066/making-data-persistent-in-android/3310108#3310108)