# Android app resume issues

Tags: android, memory

In my app, I have a loading view that sets up the app by going out to an API and bringing back some startup info to store.  I store it temporarily in an Application class.  An example of the type of data is lets say a list of servicable cities.

The flow is:

Loading View -> Main Menu -> etc etc

If I exit out of the app and come back, it usually starts with Main Menu view and hits onresume and everything is fine.  But sometimes if I wait a while and the OS clears some memory maybe, I come back and it again goes to Main Menu but this time starts from scratch for that view by calling onCreate.  But it seems like the application data is wiped.

I am just wondering why, if it is wiping the application data, is it not just starting up the app from scratch?

Is there some directive in the manifest I can make to make it do this?  Keep in mind, I dont want it to restart the app when coming back into the app from a pause.  Only when the OS has cleared the application data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the application is closed to free up memory the state of stored in your `Application` class is lost. You can save information that will persists even if you application gets closed in a few ways.

One is to use shared preferences: [Making data persistent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310066/making-data-persistent-in-android)

The other is to use `Bundles` which is probably more along the lines of what you need: [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Comment: @Jesse This is right. And please review [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Well if the application is being closed, why doesnt it start back up with the Loading View?  If that would happen, everything would be fine.

Comment: I am already using SharedPreferences for some things, but dont see why I need to here...these are simple things such as flags and a couple light weight collections.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are **perfect** for storing flags!  Collections probably belong better in a `Bundle`. The problem is that when your app closes it could be in `Paused`, `Stopped`, or `Destroyed` in the case that it is `Destroyed` nothing is left. All objects are deleted and all memory is freed. If you haven't save state using `SharedPreferences`, `Bundles`, or using a file on the disk then everything will be lost.