# If app is downloaded first time then registration comes from second time login comes

Tags: android

I am working on an app. The requirement is as: If the app is downloaded and opened first time 1) The Registration screen appears. 2) If user already has Registered, then he can skip this step3) and go to Login Screen. From second time onwards only login screen appears. 4) If app is downloaded and opened first time, Registration/Login screen appears. If user has already registered, he can simply login. From Second time onwards, direct to home page, no need to login. I am not getting any idea about this. Can some one please help me in this regard.Thanks

Comment: I am not getting from where to start?

Comment: @Shane, posting a comment rushing people to help you a minute after posting the question is rude

Comment: @Shane try finding it in google ..make some effort then come here if you stuck somewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use SharedPreferences to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use `PreferenceManager`, try reading here about storing data in your android app: [Making data persistent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310066/making-data-persistent-in-android)