# Save The value of Variable in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making data persistent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310066/making-data-persistent-in-android)

**Edited:**

I am building an android app which works on the principle of a simple counter.

```
public class TasbeehActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int count;
ImageButton imButton;
TextView display;
static String ref = "Myfile";
static String key = "key";
SharedPreferences myPrefs;
boolean check = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bCount);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
     myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(ref, 0);

     if(check){
         String dataReturned = myPrefs.getString(key, "0");
            count = Integer.parseInt(dataReturned);
            display.setText(""+count);
     }

    imButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Random rand = new Random();
            display.setTextColor(Color.rgb(rand.nextInt(255),
                    rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));
            count++;
            display.setText("" + count);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

     String data = display.getText().toString(); SharedPreferences.Editor
     editor = myPrefs.edit(); editor.putString(key, data);
     editor.commit();
     check = true;

}}
```

I want to save the value of **count** so that when my app restarts after closing it should have the value of **count** before closing app.
Also when I change orientation of the emulator i.e. from *portrait* to *landscape* or vice versa **count** gets set to 0.
Is there any solution for both of these problems?

Comment: i think you should use [SharePrefrences ](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: use intent  on android set it and when open the app just read it back

Comment: Save count value in SharedPreferences. you able to access it next time when app open again. Thanks.

Comment: I have saved the **count** value to SharedPreferences in onDestroy as at developer.android.com it is mentioned that when an app changes orientation it goes through onDestroy to onCreate. But When  try to access this value in onCreate it gives an error and application crashes because it tries to **get** value before **set** -ing. is there any other way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save your variable, and Override [OnConfigurationChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#q=onconfigurationchanged) because it's probably calling your oncreate method (don't forget to add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` in your manifest)
I Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** use [sharedpreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for saving or retrieving value of **count** when app is  restarts after closing

**2.** see [handle orientation change in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) **count** gets set to 0 when I change orientation of the emulator i.e. from portrait to landscape or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Try these....

1. `android:configChanges="orientation"` , This will prevent your Activity to again restart when orientation changes.
2. Use Bundle, but thats only for small amount of data. Serialization and Deserialization will be needed.
3. You can also use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`, for storing and retrieving data.

See this link for further details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html