# How to use Android Internal Storage?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am a beginner in java and I am building an android app.

I want to have an xml file that has text in it.
Whenever the server sends updates, I want to change some lines in that file (what I mean by update is changing some lines in that file by erasing the some part of the text written already and replace by the update)

I know nothing about creating,writing or reading from files.
When I searched I found out that Internal storage suits me best.

But I do not know if I have to create an xml file manually in any directory or just use the code bellow to create this file automatically?

```
    // If this is the first time run,execute one time code
    // create XML Internal store 

    String FILENAME = "My_XML_file";
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use Shared Prefrence in android. See my  post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639899/shared-preferences-in-android/12640072#12640072

Answer (score 0):

**-** First give the `External Storage permission` in the Manifest.xml file.

**-** You can use `JAXP & JAXB`, and even `CASTOR` to handle XML in a better way, but still `DOM` and `SAX` are inbuilt into Android.

- You can use something like this

  `String s = "/sdcard/Myfolder/mytext.txt";`

  `File f = new File(s);`

Comment: @Kumar Vivek Mitra why would I use external storage permission if i am using internal storage?

Comment: There is no certainty that /sdcard directory will exists

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will create a file in internal storage but you need a bit more to create and maintain an XML file easily.
I suggest you use the Build in Android DOM Parser [(Android developers site docs on XML Parse options)](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html)

I found this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) which explains how to use the dom parser to build a specific (new) XML file from code. In your context where the output stream in created:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));
```

you might want to use the other constructor based on the output stream you created above

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fos);
```

In a similar fashion this DOM library allows you to read from an input stream (which you might get from android openFileInput) using DocumentBuilder.parse()