# How to make login cookie like system

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and i have build a login system that works with a web server. I was wondering what the best way to make a cookie like system for android so that everytime the user goes into the app they do not have to log in again. What would be the best way to do this? Any information to steer me on the right track would be great!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you make make auto Login in Android App like Skype does.

Comment: If you talk to your server over HTTP, there's no reason you can't use the same cookie login solution in your Android app, too.

Comment: hmmm that could work :) yeah i will investigate! :)

Comment: Use SharedPreference to store your credential details.

Comment: @Nicholas you can use Android SharedPreference property see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639899/shared-preferences-in-android/12640072#12640072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Web Service, you need to make use of username password every time you use a service.

I am not sure, but if you define your application as service, your application will keep running in background and the user will remain logged in the whole time, unless he logs out by himself/herself. So, no need to maintain cookie.

Thanks & Regards,

Krishna V. Mahadik