# How to set Password while opening my android app

Tags: android

I want my android application, password protected. How can I set password on my app. Please help me in this respect, your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If this isn't something you could answer with a quick search I'll eat my shoe.

Comment: Why have you devoted the question?

Comment: @user1703737 I not do down vote for your question, even yesterday I done up voted for it. But if you ask such question this will happen. First search in google then ask question.

Comment: @Akhilesh Mani, dear thanks for your positive comments.

Comment: @user1703737 welcom.... Keep it up !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639899/shared-preferences-in-android/12640072#12640072). You can use shared preferences of android for doing so.