# SharedPreferences issue in my toggle

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, togglebutton

I've got a problem using sharedpreferences in my toggle button. First, i declared what i need:

```
public SharedPreferences preferences;
public WifiManager wifiManager;
ToggleButton wifitoggle;
```

Then the "action" onClikc

```
// toggle wifi
    public void wifi (View view) {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        boolean wifion = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        if (wifion) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            // Shared preferences
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("togglewifi", true); // value to store
            editor.commit();

        }else{
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            // Shared preferences
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("togglewifi", false); // value to store
            editor.commit();

        }
    }
```

and in my onCreate i reported the value:

```
boolean togglewifi = preferences.getBoolean("togglewifi", false);  //default è false
        if (togglewifi) 
        {

            wifitoggle.setChecked(true);
        }
            else
        {
            wifitoggle.setChecked(false);
        }
```

But when i run the application it crashes. The strange thing is that the logCat say nothing. No errors.. Have i missed something? Thanks for help

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there is nothing in logcat? Try filtering for errors, it is likely you're missing a permission to interact with the WifiManager.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639899/shared-preferences-in-android/12640072#12640072 you can refer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```java
SharedPreferences sPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
Editor editor = sPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("KEY", true/false);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: where `PREFS_NAME` is like `static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferences";`?

Comment: anyway: `The method putBoolean(String, boolean) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)`

Comment: yes, PREFS_NAME is like static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferences";

Comment: only one thing, this your code have i to put over `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("togglewifi", true); // value to store
            editor.commit();`? or in onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your sharedprefereneces.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
```

Here, sharedPreferenceName should be a name through which you are going to access the value stored. If it does not match, you won't be able to access the value in sharedpreference.