# Writing a list to a file and reading from it

Tags: java, android

I have looked around but have not been able to find anything related. I have 3 Lists (week, day, period) I need to write them to a file so that they are not deleted when the app is closed. How would I write these lists to a file and then when the app is open read them back into a List as they were before. Not sure if this is a stupid question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making data persistent in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310066/making-data-persistent-in-android)

Comment: If the data is not too big you can easily store them using Shared Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some examples in the [android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Basically, you can use File like in Java, for example to write (from android doc):

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```