# How to manage time while app is closed?

Tags: android

In my new app i need to manage time while the user is not in the app.

For example, when the user leaves the app and comes back an hour later, a task they wanted done is now done after that hour.

What is the best way to make this happen?

Comment: What is the problem? You save the task end time and in `onResume()` or so you compare it to the actual time.

Answer (score 2):

[Making data persistent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310066/making-data-persistent-in-android)
Like Simon said, store a timestamp when app closes or your task is started then when you resume compare it to that time stamp to discover the elapsed time.

Comment: Thats a good way to do it. The only problem i can see with this us..What if the user leaves the app at a certain time stamp like 2:00am. then come back to the app at exactly 2:00pm. That means the time stamp will be the same right? This means nothing will happen even though 12 hours have lapsed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android I don't believe timestamps reset every 12, or even every 24 hours but you can use a Calendar, a Date or something else, there are many ways to get the time.